# Background image in div

Tags: html

I have a div containing some text with a background image. The div's width is not fixed. I want to show the right part of the background image by default, and then show more of the image to the left if the text grows longer. How do I do this?

Comment: You could start with some online research. Maybe even a book or two. Please don't post asking SO to do something to your specification without at least attempting it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `background-position`:

```
.mydiv {
    background-position: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `background-position`.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#divid {
    background-position: right;
}
```